# Equation of the line passing through $(3,-2,-5)$ and $(3,-2,6)$

Tags: vectors, 3d

> Find the Cartesian equation of the line passing through $(3,-2,-5)$ and $(3,-2,6)$ in $3$D.

The equation of the line through the points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ is given by
$$
\vec{r}=\vec{a}+\lambda(\vec{b}-\vec{a})
$$
where $\vec{a}=x_1\hat{i}+y_1\hat{j}+z_1\hat{k}$ and $\vec{b}-\vec{a}=(x_2-x_1)\hat{i}+(y_2-y_1)\hat{j}+(z_2-z_1)\hat{k}$
$$
\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1}=\frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1}
$$

For the line through the points $(3,-2,-5)$ and $(3,-2,6)$ is
$$\lambda=
\boxed{\frac{x-3}{0}=\frac{y+2}{0}=\frac{z+5}{11}}
$$

Is it the correct solution and how do I make sense of the final equation of the line through the given points ?

Comment: There can't be a single equation for a line in dimension $3$.

Comment: @Bernard Its 2 equations really.

Comment: @Sorfosh: Yes, of course, but the O.P. was about `the` equation…

Comment: ofcause its two equations. but my doubt is in the equation there is 0 in the denominator, and how do I make sense of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we should divide by zero.

Observe the first two coordinates of the points.

They satisfy $x=3$ and $y=-2$.

The line is the intersection of $x=3$ and $y=-2$.

The formula is only used when $x_1 \ne x_2$, $y_1 \ne y_2$, and $z_1 \ne z_2$.

Comment: thats whr my doubt is. how do we justify dividing by 0 in the equation ?

Comment: hmm.. we dont' divide by zero. If the values are the same in $x$ coordiante, we know the lines falls on $x=x_0$.

Comment: I think the problem is you do not understand where the equation of the line comes from. Your goal is to eliminate the parameter $t$, so you really just do nothing if the constant in front of it is $0$

Comment: This [article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/3d-coordinate-geometry-equation-of-a-line/) might be of your interest, notice that they impose the condition that denominator is non-zero. Also, the article later describe what to do when the values are equal in a particular dimension.

Comment: So what'd be the equation of the plane through the points $(3,-2,-5)$ and $(3,-2,6)$ ?. I have seen in few books it is written as $\frac{x-3}{0}=\frac{y+2}{0}=\frac{z+5}{11}$. But, 0 in the denominator seems absurd to me. Can I write the equation as rather $x=3, y=-2$ ?

Comment: Yes, $x=3, y=-2$. Books are written by humans. Not everything that is written is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Set $A=(3,-2,-5)$, $B=(3,-2,6)$. As  any point on the line $(AB)$ is a barycenter $\lambda A+(1-lambda)B$ of $A$ and $B$, the coordinates of a point $M$ of this line are obtained by projections on the axes of this relation:
\begin{cases}
x_M=\lambda\cdot 2+(1-\lambda)2=2, \\
y_M=\lambda(-3)+(1-\lambda)(-3)=-3,\\
z_M=-5\lambda+6(1-\lambda)=6-11\lambda.
\end{cases}
This is a parametric representation, and we see that $z_M$ can take any real value, so the cartesian equations are:
\begin{cases}
x=2, \\
y=-3.
\end{cases}

Answer (score 1):

In $2$-D, how would you find the line passing through $(3,-5)$ and $(3,6)$? Note that the formula 
$$\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1} \ \ \text{or} \ \ \frac{x-x_1}{y-y_1}=\frac{x_2-x_1}{y_2-y_1}$$
shows the slope of the line. Thus:
$$\frac{x-3}{y+5}=\frac{0}{11} \Rightarrow x-3=0 \Rightarrow x=3.$$
Indeed, it is a vertical line $x=3$ ($y$ can be any value).

Similarly, the line passing through $(3,-2,-5)$ and $(3,-2,6)$ is a vertical line $x=3,y=-2$ ($z$ can be any value).

Answer (score 0):

By your work $\vec{(0,0,1)}$ is parallel to the line, which gives the answer:
$$(x,y,z)=(3,-2,-5)+t(0,0,1).$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $$x=3, y=-2$$

For $z$ may use parametric form $$z=-5+11t$$

Thus your equation is $$r(t) = (3,-2,-5+11t)$$

Answer (score 0):

To make sense of the Division by 0, we have to first see the derivation of this formula to understand what the denominator actually means in this formula.

[image: Diagram1]

Lets say, we need to write the function for the line $l$ and we have been given that the line passes through a fixed point $A$ and is parallel to vector $\vec B$ .

Now, let $\vec a = \vec {OA}$

Put the tail of $\vec b$ on $A$

We have $\vec r = \vec a + \lambda\vec b$ such that the tip of $\vec r$ always lies on line $l$.

If we write our results in cartesian form, where

$\vec r = x \hat{i}+y \hat{j} + z\hat{k}$

$\vec a = x_1 \hat{i}+ y_1 \hat{j} + z_1\hat{k}$

$\vec b = a \hat{i}+b \hat{j} + c\hat{k}$

Here, $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ is the given point through which $l$ passes and $(a, b, c)$ are direction ratio of $\vec b$.

Putting these in the previously derived equation,

$$
\lambda=\frac{x-x_1}{a}=\frac{y-y_1}{b}=\frac{z-z_1}{c}
$$

This formula can be modified if two points are given since the direction ratio of the line passing through $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ would be just the difference of respective coordinates i.e $(x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1, z_2- z_1)$. So you just replace $(a, b ,c)$ with these coordinates to get your formula.

As you can see here, the denominators are actually the direction ratio of $\vec b$. So when you get

$$\lambda=
\boxed{\frac{x-3}{0}=\frac{y+2}{0}=\frac{z+5}{11}}
$$

what it actually means is that direction ratio(or cosine) of $\vec b$ along $X$ and $Y$ axis is $0$.

Remember direction cosine is actually the cosine of the angle made by a vector with the 3 axes.

[image: diagram2]

So in this case, your

$$\boxed{cos(\alpha) = cos(\beta) = 0}$$

i.e
$$\boxed{\alpha = \beta = \frac{\pi}{2}}$$

So that would mean your line $l$ would make $90°$ with $X$ and $Y$ axis respectively.

**Note that this does not mean that your line would be the $Z$ axis. Your line $l$ could be any line which which is perpendicular to the $XY$ plane.**

From the given points you can try to visualise that $l$ will intersect $XY$ plane **perpendicularly** at point $(3, -2, 0)$